# Dealing with mirrored inheritance trees

Tags: c#, oop

Quite often I find myself dealing with a pattern similar to this one

[image]

Two inheritance trees, where there is some kind of mirroring. Each of the subclasses in the left tree has a different subclass in the right tree as `source`

The MappingEnd class:

```
public class MappingEnd
{
    public NamedElement source { get; set; }
}
```

The question is, how to deal with that in the subclasses. Do I hide the parent `source` property using the `new` keyword?

```
public class AssociationMappingEnd:MappingEnd
{
    public new Association source { get; set; }
}
```

Or do I simply provide a second property casting the `NamedElement` to `Association` ?

```
public class AssociationMappingEnd:MappingEnd
{
    public Association associationSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (Association)this.source;
        }
        set
        {
            this.source = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Why would I choose one over the other. Or is there a better way to implement this type of pattern?

Comment: Generics? Something like `class MappingEnd<TElementType> where TElementType : NamedElement` with `public TElementType source {get;set;}` perhaps?

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, that might work, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first design, `public new Association source` can easily cause trouble. You can still access the hidden member `public NamedElement source` accidentally. which is not cool.

For example, look at this pseudo-code:

```
IEnumerable<MappingEnd> MyMixedCollection = all kinds of MappingEnd objects

((AssociationMappingEnd)MyMixedCollection.First()).source //is cool
MyMixedCollection.First().source //access the hidden member, not cool
```

The `new` keyword is not the best design practice because it doesn't hide the inherited member. What it does is basically hiding the *warning message* that comes without it.

I personally *never* consider this as a valid design.

---

The second design is much more reliable because these names never get mixed up

```
AssociationMappingEnd.associationSource is Association
AssociationMappingEnd.source            is NamedElement

MappingEnd.source                       is NamedElement
```

However, it can get confusing since these `source` and `associationSource` are actually the same. It works, but it can be better.

---

We can't use `override` on `source` and give it a new type, we could use `public virtual NamedElement source`, but then we would lost **type-safety**. To retain type-safety we can use Generics, as elgonzo suggested.

The left side needs to be generic, because it depends on the types of its right side classes, so we should start with the top class on the left side:

```
public class MappingEnd<T> where T : NamedElement
{
    public T source { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can have either or both of these classes:

```
public class AssociationMappingEnd<T> : MappingEnd<T> where T : Association
{
}

public class AssociationMappingEnd : MappingEnd<Association>
{
}
```

Now you got only one `source` with a safe type:

```
AssociationMappingEnd<Association>.source   is Association
AssociationMappingEnd.source                is Association

MappingEnd<NamedElement>.source             is NamedElement
MappingEnd<Association>.source              is Association
```

Comment: Thx, great answer. I think I prefer the public class `AssociationMappingEnd : MappingEnd<Association>` version most. About accessing the hidden member in the first scenario, that would not really be a problem since it would still return the same object, only now typed as `NameElement` and not as `Association`

Comment: @GeertBellekens, Of course, you can hide the member if you are completely sure the implementation will never change, but once you add extra logic to the getter or setter of `associationSource` the problem begins to emerge.